# Multiple levels of have_many in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many-through

I am working with Ruby on Rails (specifically the ActiveRecord) and I am trying to decide whether or not it is a good idea to link my models using multiple levels.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_sections
  has_many :sections, :through => :student_sections
  has_many :courses, :through => :sections
end
```

It seems like this would work, but I don't have a lot of experience in ActiveRecord. Is there any reason not to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fine but you should bear in mind that the courses association is effectively only a 'get' association (as opposed to 'get and set').  What i mean by that is that you can say

@student.courses

(after doing neo's fix) to get a list of courses, but you can't do

@student.courses << @course

as rails doesn't have the section info required to make the necessary joins between the student and the course.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add :source attribute

```
has_many :sections, :through => :student_sections, :source => 'your_source'
```

Comment: Why would he need to add a source? Rails should be able to determine the association automatically in this case.

Comment: rdoc writed: "Specifies the source association name used by has_many :through queries. Only use it if the name cannot be inferred from the association. has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscriptions will look for either :subscribers or :subscriber on Subscription, unless a :source is given."

Comment: My model is set up so that I don't need to use :source, but thank you.